# Unable to fetch the branch since the reference branches are deleted

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-fetch

I was trying to pull git branch `bugfix/validator-integration-bugfix` using following command
`git fetch && git checkout bugfix/validator-integration-bugfix`

but I am getting following error:

```
akshaykhale$ git fetch && git checkout bugfix/validator-integration-bugfix
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix/connection-failure-bugfix': 'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix/connection-failure-bugfix'
From https://github.com/luxio/luxio-framework
 ! [new branch]          bugfix/connection-failure-bugfix -> origin/bugfix/connection-failure-bugfix  (unable to update local ref)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix/migration-datatype-bugfix': 'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix/migration-datatype-bugfix'
 ! [new branch]          bugfix/migration-datatype-bugfix                  -> origin/bugfix/migration-datatype-bugfix  (unable to update local ref)
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix/validator-integration-bugfix': 'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/bugfix/validator-integration-bugfix'
 ! [new branch]          bugfix/validator-integration-bugfix                           -> origin/bugfix/validator-integration-bugfix  (unable to update local ref)
```

Possible reason could be (just a guess):

I am fetching `bugfix/validator-integration-bugfix` branch which is created from other branches which were not cloned on my development system.

any way to fix the issue

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `git fetch --prune` worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me:

```
git fetch --prune
```

With `git prune` it pulled all the branches, I could switch to the required branch and able to push in the commits without any issues.

Thank you [@MarkAdelsberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7050130/mark-adelsberger)

Answer (score 2):

Someone on your team has created a branch named `bugfix` and pushed it to `origin/bugfix`. Git will not allow you to create a branch with a name of the format `origin/bugfix/*` because of this.

I'm guessing the branch was named `bugfix` by mistake, so the solution is to give this branch a more descriptive name.

To rename the `bugfix` branch locally:

`git branch -m bugfix bugfix/sensible-name`

Then to rename it on your remote:

`git push origin :bugfix bugfix/sensible-name`

Then set the renamed local branch to track the renamed remote branch:

`git push origin -u bugfix/sensible-name`

Comment: I think this is on he right track, but since the error seems to be coming from `fetch` I think the problem ref exists locally rather than on the remote.  (It would take a few steps to get into this state, but possible.)  In that case, a `git fetch --prune` might be sufficient

Comment: `git fetch --prune` worked, @MarkAdelsberger Please post this as an answer so that I can accept and close the question, Thanks!!!